# Write to excel file using apache poi using selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

Please before you down vote this, I was not able to find an example of reading a web table and writing it to an Excel file. If you happen to find that link kindly provide it. I have found plenty of examples on how to write to an Excel file but without reading from web table part.

Here is my code:

```
public class WebTable1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp");

        //tr means Row, this table has 7 rows including Header
        ///td means Column, this table has 3 columns

        //*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]
        //*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]
        //Notice above the pattern, only the values are changing for tr[??]- which is why we will break it down into 2 String
        //below and then concatinate them as String

        String beforeXpath_Company = "//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr["; // changed customer to single quote
        String aferXpath_Company = "]/td[1]";  //Company is column 1

        String beforeXpath_Contact = "//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr[";
        String aferXpath_Contact = "]/td[2]";  // Contact is column 2

        String beforeXpath_Country = "//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr[";
        String aferXpath_Country = "]/td[3]";  // Country is column 3

        //Find number of rows so that we do not use hard coded values
        List<WebElement> totalRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']//tr"));
        int rows=totalRows.size();



        for (int i = 2; i <rows; i++) {  //we start from 2 because  1 is column name
            String actualXpath = beforeXpath_Company + i + aferXpath_Company;
            String companyName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath)).getText();
            System.out.println(companyName);

            String actualXpath_Contact = beforeXpath_Contact + i + aferXpath_Contact;
            String contactName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_Contact)).getText();
            System.out.println(contactName);

            String actualXpath_Country = beforeXpath_Country + i + aferXpath_Country;
            String countryName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_Country)).getText();
            System.out.println(countryName);

           //Try to following to write to an Excel file in C drive
            Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
            Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

            Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(createHelper.createRichTextString(companyName));

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\MyTemp\\Test.xls");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Any problem with the code? Apart from the fact that you create and write out a whole workbook in the for loop, overwriting any previous output...

Comment: I want the data in a nice Excel format.

Comment: You have to read all the data from the table, form an object model and store all the data from the table. Finally use Apache POI to write to an excel sheet. I do not think there is direct way to write to an excel sheet from a web table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your existing table extraction code, you can do something like this:

```
public class WebTable1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp");

    String beforeXpath_Company = "//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr["; // changed customer to single quote
    String aferXpath_Company = "]/td[1]";  //Company is column 1

    String beforeXpath_Contact = "//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr[";
    String aferXpath_Contact = "]/td[2]";  // Contact is column 2

    String beforeXpath_Country = "//*[@id='customers']/tbody/tr[";
    String aferXpath_Country = "]/td[3]";  // Country is column 3

    //Find number of rows so that we do not use hard coded values
    List<WebElement> totalRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='customers']//tr"));
    int rows=totalRows.size();


    // Create a workbook and a sheet in it
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

    // Create a table header
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Company name");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Contact name");
    row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Country");


    for (int i = 2; i <rows; i++) {  //we start from 2 because  1 is column name
        String actualXpath = beforeXpath_Company + i + aferXpath_Company;
        String companyName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath)).getText();

        String actualXpath_Contact = beforeXpath_Contact + i + aferXpath_Contact;
        String contactName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_Contact)).getText();

        String actualXpath_Country = beforeXpath_Country + i + aferXpath_Country;
        String countryName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_Country)).getText();

        Row row = sheet1.createRow(i - 1);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(companyName);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(contactName);
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(countryName);
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\MyTemp\\Test.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
  }
}
```